# inline css not working for my li

Tags: jquery, html, css

i tried like following to set a new `background hover color`to my `li tag`
but i'm failed to set

please guide me in syntax.

```
  <nav class="icons-example">
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="font-icon-social-facebook" style=":hover a { background-color: blue;}"></span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><span class="font-icon-social-tweeter" style=":hover a { background-color: nevyblue;}"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

in css file

```
.icons-example ul li:hover a,
.icons-example ul li.active a {
background-color: red;  
}
```

i want to set blue color as hover please help me.

yes i can make change in `css` itself but i need to change color of each `li` separatly
for example for `facebook blue` for `tweeter navyblue`.?

> can any one give me exact css change for each li

Comment: updated my exact problem please comment @Richard

Comment: The answer doesn't change.  You can't do it.  You'll need to use different classes per LI or use javascript.

Comment: oh please can any one give me exact css change for each li

Comment: What stopping you from using jquery

Comment: if simple css trick can be helpful why to use jquery :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
.icons-example ul li:hover a,
.icons-example ul li.active a {
background-color: red;  
}

.icons-example ul li:hover a span.font-icon-social-facebook,
.icons-example ul li.active a span.font-icon-social-facebook {
background-color: blue;  
}

.icons-example ul li:hover a span.font-icon-social-twitter,
.icons-example ul li.active a span.font-icon-social-twitter {
background-color: navy;  
}
```

and so on…

Answer (score 3):

The [style attribute for HTML elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-css-style-attr-20131003/) only supports CSS properties.  It does not support CSS selectors.

In order to achieve different colors for each list item, you will need to target each one individually in your stylesheet. Something to the effect of:

```
.icons-example ul li:hover a,
.icons-example ul li.active a {
    background-color: red;  
}

.icons-example ul li:hover .font-icon-social-facebook
{
    background-color: blue;  
}
```

You may wish to add a class attribute of "facebook" to that element's LI, so you could do something like:

```
.icons-example ul li.facebook:hover a
{
    background-color: blue;  
}
```

Comment: what is the solution then :(

Answer (score 1):

Add the declaration to your stylesheet

```
.icons-example ul li.active a {
  background-color: red;  
}
.icons-example ul li.active a span:hover {
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

Comment: modified my exact problem in question

Answer (score 0):

Inline css is the **direct** style for that DOM object.

You ***cannot*** tell it `style=":hover a { background-color: blue;}"`

Comment: what is the solution then :(

Comment: Use the stylesheet or do the inline css directly on the item you want to style.